# Appending to a list from one method calling from another method

Tags: python, list, class, methods

I have a class with several methods. One method creates an empty list, another method appends one item to that list and there is another which uses the first one to create a list and then the 2nd one for appending numbers through a loop, so that in the end, the empty list will become a populated list.

This is my code:

```
class CV:
    def create_metrics(self):
        self.a_list = []

    def add(self):
        self.a_list=self.a_list.append(self.number)

    def bucle(self):
        self.create_metrics()
        for i in range(3):
            self.number = 3*i
            self.add()

a = CV()
a.bucle()
```

However, I am getting the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`. If I run

```
a = CV()
a.create_metrics()
a.a_list
```

It can be checked that effectively, the list has been created and is empty, so I have no idea why when I run the complete code it is created a NoneType object.

The desired output would be `a_list = [0,3,6]`

Comment: Because `.append` returns `None`

Comment: Just make @juanpa.arrivillaga comment explicit: you don't want `self.a_list=self.a_list.append(self.number)`, `self.a_list.append(self.number)` is sufficient because it alters the list in place.

Comment: Thanks to both, it worked